# 16 people from various countries are competing. How many possible podium outcomes by country are there?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

16 people are competing
3 are from Japan,
2 each from the US, China, Australia, Brazil, and Hungary
1 each from Canada, Spain, and South Africa.

1. How many possible podium outcomes by country are there? (Ex. Gold: China, Silver: Spain, Bronze: China, would be 1 valid combination)
2. Based solely on the number of athletes per country in the semi-finals and not on their relative swimming abilities:
   a. What is the probability that Canada will earn at least one medal?
   b. What is the probability that Hungary will earn at least one medal?
   c .What is the probability that Japan will earn at least one medal?

Comment: What are your own ideas about this? Add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $9$ countries competing, hence there are $9\cdot 8\cdot 7$ podiums made by different countries. There is only $1$ podium made by a single country (Japan) and we have to count how many podiums can be conquered by exactly two different countries. There are $6$ countries with at least two athletes and a selected couple of athletes may leave out position $1$, $2$ or $3$ for an athlete from another country. So the possible podiums are

$$ 9\cdot 8\cdot 7 + 1 + 6\cdot 3\cdot 8 = 649. $$

To answer the second question I seem to miss a crucial information, i.e. which probability distribution are we assuming on the set of the possible podiums. Do we select three athletes uniformly at random from the $16$ athletes competing? If so, Japan is out of the podium with a probability equal to $\frac{\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{16}{3}}=\frac{143}{280}$, hence there is at least one japanese in the podium with probability $\frac{137}{280}\approx 48.9\%$. Similarly, the probability that Hungary will earn a medal is $1-\frac{\binom{14}{3}}{\binom{16}{3}}\approx 35\%$ and the probability that Canada will earn a medal is $1-\frac{\binom{15}{3}}{\binom{16}{3}}\approx 18.75\%$.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure. All the information I've been given is in the question. It says to base it on the # of athletes per country, not their relative skill. So my thinking is each individual would have a 1/16 chance at earning a medal, and a increasing chance for countries with more swimmers?

Comment: @Ruhe: I am going to update the answer with a reasonable interpretation.